# C# Set and get Value from input text in .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I think my problem is quite easy, but I find no solution:

My Question:
If I set a  field by C#, I modify it in the browser, the value will still be the same.

Example

```
<input type="text" id="IdText" runat="server" />
```

Set it with c# (load data into the form, with page.aspx?id=2, get data from DB and set itz to input fields)

```
IdText.Value = "Example";
```

Modify it in the browser, I insert "MyExample", and click a button to update the DB
And if I will request the Value with c# it's still the same.

```
string text = IdText.Value;
```

Here the Value is "Example", and not "MyExample".

Do I have to add some more code?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using ASP.NET controls like `TextBox`?

Comment: Wrap your pageLoad code inside if(!Page.IsPostback) { // your code } block to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Damien in the comment, you should wrap the code block that sets the `Text`-property to the value from DB in a `!IsPostBack`-check. Otherwise you're overwriting the changed value with the old from DB since `Page_Load` is executed before the button-click event-handler.

For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(OBject sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        IdText.Value = "Example";
    }
}
```

I would also use `ASP.NET`-controls if i use `ASP.NET`, so a `TextBox` instead of a html-input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
I knew the solution is easy.

As I'm using boostrap, I think it is quiet hard to combine bootstrap with the asp.net controls.
But you are right - I could use `<asp:textbox>` insted of `<input type="text" />`

Thanks 
Mike